# Applying for UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipina who is working as a teacher. I'd like to visit my boyfriend in the UK. How can I obtain a visa?

Answer (score 2):

> **How will I obtain a [UK] visa?**

The process is explained at the [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa)

For a Standard Visitor Visa you can [Apply using the UK Access Service](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa)

If applying in the Phillipines you may need to attend an appointment at a visa application centre in Cebu or Manila.